# Simultaneous WorkItem save in TFS server

Tags: c#

According to our requirements need to Assign a workitem at parent level and also at its tree level like child workItems.

```
foreach (WorkItem ari in queryResultsARI)
{
if(ari.Fields["Assigned To"].Value.Equals(""))
{                                       
ari.Open();
ari.Fields["Assigned To"].Value = Name;
ari.Fields["Lab"].Value = Location;
ari.Save(SaveFlags.MergeAll);                                       
Thread.Sleep(2000); //give delay for 3 sec to get assigned name, lab location updated in TFS DB
foreach (WorkItemLink varient in ari.Links.WorkItem.WorkItemLinks)
 {
   WorkItem vri = workItemStore.GetWorkItem(varient.TargetId);
   vri.Open();
   vri.Fields["Assigned To"].Value = Name;
   vri.Fields["Lab"].Value = Location;
   vri.Save(SaveFlags.MergeAll);
   Thread.Sleep(2000);
 foreach (WorkItemLink workorder in vri.Links.WorkItem.WorkItemLinks)
  {
   if (workorder.LinkTypeEnd.Name == "Child")
    {
     WorkItem wri = workItemStore.GetWorkItem(workorder.TargetId);
     wri.Open();
     wri.Fields["Assigned To"].Value = Name;
     wri.Fields["Lab"].Value = Location;
     wri.Save(SaveFlags.MergeAll);
     Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

But assigned to workitem field is saving for multiple instances who are trying to save. Even SaveFlags.MergeAll didn't help.

Could someone assist us on the same issue. We are suspecting like its timing issue with TFS, for which we need to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all workitems’ ID which linked to a particular workitem with the code snippet:

```
    TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("URL"));
    WorkItemStore workitemstores = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
    WorkItem workitem = workitemstores.GetWorkItem(ID);
    if(workitem.Links.Count!=0)
    {
        foreach (Link link in workitem.Links)
        {
            RelatedLink relatedLink = link as RelatedLink;
            if (relatedLink != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(relatedLink.RelatedWorkItemId);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then put all these work items in an array, and modify the Assigned To field one by one.